# Reusing valve stem seals

Tags: valve, seal

I just lapped my valves on a cylinder because they were leaking and reused the stem seals. Should I put new stem seals or is it okay to reuse them?

Comment: Have you considered self-sealing stem bolts?

Comment: @AlexanderKlauer I dunno what that is

Comment: SCNR https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Self-sealing_stem_bolt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you believe the seals are in good shape, there's nothing saying you can't reuse them. However, considering you have it all apart and the seals are relatively cheap considering the amount of time it would take to tear it all apart to replace these specifically, it only makes sense to replace them while you're in there. Time isn't a big deal, but when you consider where the seals are at, it does take a considerable amount to replace them. Realistically it is up to you whether they get replace. If I had ***any doubt*** about them, there would be new ones in place.

Answer (score 5):

As inexpensive as those seals are, and as hard as they are to get to, you should absolutely replace them.

Do not reuse them.